# Is there a variant of the KKM lemma in which the sets correspond to permutations?

Tags: co.combinatorics

The [KKM lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski%E2%80%93Mazurkiewicz_lemma) considers an $n$-vertex simplex which is covered by $n$ sets - a set for each vertex. It says that, if each face is covered by the union of sets corresponding to its corners, then the common intersection of all $n$ sets is nonempty.

The [KKMS lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski%E2%80%93Mazurkiewicz_lemma#The_KKMS_theorem) extends the KKM lemma by allowing $2^n-1$ sets - a set for each nonempty subset of vertices. It says that, if each face is covered by the union of sets corresponding to its sub-faces, then there is a "balanced collection" of sets (not necessarily all $2^n-1$ of them), such that the common intersection of all sets in the collection is nonempty.

My question is: is there another extension of the lemma, in which there are $n!$ sets - a set for each *permutation* of vertices?

[My guess is that, if each face is covered by sets corresponding to permutations in which its corners appear first, then there is a collection of sets corresponding to a cyclic permutation, such that the common intersection of all sets in the collection is nonempty. For example, for $n=3$ we would have $3!=6$ sets and the following boundary conditions:

- The vertex 1 should be covered by the sets (123), (132).
- The vertex 2 should be covered by the sets (123), (132).
- The vertex 3 should be covered by the sets (123), (132).
- The face 12 should be covered by the sets (123), (213).
- The face 23 should be covered by the sets (231), (321).
- The face 31 should be covered by the sets (312), (132).

The "lemma" would say that, in this case, either the sets (123, 231, 312) or the sets (132, 321, 213) have a nonempty intersection].